# Redirect Input stream from AWS S3 response to Http Servlet response

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, filestream

I have a very large file to download from S3 or any other datasource. Is it possible to redirect that stream from S3 to outputstream of Http response without loading it in my application memory. Is it possible or am I crazy ?